# Fourier transform of the dipolar interaction

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I am not sure how to compute the following integral:

$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \, \frac{e^{ikx}}{(x^2 + a^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$

where $a$ is a real and positive parameter.

I tried to use complex integration. However there are no simple poles due to the $3/2$ exponent.
At the moment I don't know how to proceed, so if you could help me I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Start with $I = 2\,\int_0^{\infty}\, \frac{e^{ikx}}{(x^2 + a^2)^{3/2}}\,dx$, then introduce the keyhole contour.

Comment: It's a Bessel $K$ function, using [Basset's integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I(a)$ be given by the Fourier transform

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac1a \frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{(x^2+a^2)^{1/2}}\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac1a \frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i|ka|x}}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}}\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac1a \frac{d}{da}\int_0^\infty e^{-|ka|\cosh(x)}\,dx\tag1\\\\
&=-\frac2a \frac{d}{da}K_0(|ka|) \tag2\\\\
&=2\left|\frac{k}{a}\right|K_1(|ka|)
\end{align}$$

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we made use of [THIS REFERENCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1),

Comment: $\displaystyle +1$. Good job.

Comment: @FelixMarin Hello my friend!  It's been a long while.  How are you?

Comment: That's great, thank you so much

Comment: @ofey You're welcome.  My pleasure